# HOw to make mysql query based on multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to make a query based on multiple checkboxes.(For exapmle for e-shop )

Checkboxes

```
         <div id="car">       
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="red" >red</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="black" >black</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="blue" >blue</label>          
          </div>


        <div id="brand">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="mazda" >mazda</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="bmw" >bmw</label>

        </div>
```

Query

```
 $brand = $_POST['brand'];
 $color = $_POST['color'];

$Query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE brand IN ('" . implode("','", $brand) . "') and color IN ('" . implode("','", $color) . "')";


$QueryResult = mysqli_query($connection , $Query);


while($QueryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)){
?>
<div><p><?php echo $QueryRow['cost'];?></p></div>
<div><img src="<?php echo $QueryRow['img']; ?>"></div>
<?php
}
}
    ?>
```

Also , I have js script for passing array with values taken from checkboxes, but it doesn't related to problem, that is why I do not post script.

Problem:

How to avoid error if COLOR-check box have not been checked?

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you have a color column into items table?

Comment: Implode with quotes `"SELECT * FROM items WHERE brand IN ('" . implode("','", $brand) . "')";`

Comment: The "color unchecked error" is that the POST variable doesn't has a key color? Answer these two questions so that I can make a more concise answer.

Comment: Yes, it means that from file with checkboxes, empty color array was passed

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE brand IN ('" . implode("','", $brand) . "') and color IN ('" . implode("','", $color) . "')";
```

Comment: it's good,but what if COLOR-checkbox is not choosen, then it wiil give error

Comment: i haven't sufficient reputation so only i post the answer